# How to accurately detect when table scrolled to the very bottom?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I currently have this code to detect when user reached the last element in the data list

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if (indexPath.row == list.count) {
        self.getMoreData()
    }       
    return cell
}
```

It works very well as long as I don't leave the view. if I leave the view and return to it with a back action, this method is executed until it reaches `list.count - X`, where `X` is the amount of ítems that are visible in the screen.

An example: If I have 18 ítems, this method runs until 11 on iPhone 6+ when navigating back to list.

This causes my logic to detect last item to fail. I have no idea what's going on :(

Comment: what is index? There's no such variable in your code

Comment: @FyzaNawaz: I'm really sorry, it was a tipo when removing noise to from my real code

Comment: Have you tried debugging? This condition must not be true in every case. I think there's some other issue, somewhere else

Comment: Obviusly I debugged, it reaches certain number and  stops there.

Comment: @FyzaNawaz: condition is not always true. It's always false :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace "index" with "indexPath.row".

Comment: @StackOverflower, let me know if it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    if(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y =< scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        // bottom
    }
}
```